# Leaflet js working on localhost, but not working when opening from Harddisk

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I have a JS which uses Leaflet to display a map. It works, when I open it on a remote server or using XAMPP on localhost.

But the Openstreetmap Tiles are NOT displayed / working when opening it just as HTML-file from my harddrive in the Browser, e.g. the URL-Bar showing an "address" like C:\xampp\htdocts\test.html.

The code is pretty straight forward, nothing fancy:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    
    <style>
     #map {
        margin-top: 100px; 
        width: 100%; 
        height: 650px; 
        border: 1px solid #AAA; 
    }
    <title>Leaflet Map</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
         integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
         crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
         integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
         crossorigin=""></script>
         
    <div id="map"></div>
        
    <script language="javascript">
    let map;
    let mapInitialized;
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
    {        
        // Map erzeugen und auf die Schweiz zoomen + TileLayer einbinden
        if($('#map').length > 0) {
            map = L.map('map').setView([50, 10.8], 6);
            L.tileLayer('https://tiles.stadiamaps.com/tiles/osm_bright/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
                maxZoom: 13,
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://stadiamaps.com/">Stadia Maps</a>, &copy; <a href="https://openmaptiles.org/">OpenMapTiles</a> &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            }).addTo(map);
            mapInitialized = true;
        }        
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**
By "not working", I mean, the map is actually looking as if it is initialized, but the tiles are not shown. Is it more a Browser specific thing, because I just found out the tiles are "blocked" (it seems) by the Browser, showing in the console:
[image]
You can see the URL of stadiamaps tiles being blocked.

I'm not looking for a particular fix, as I'm obviously using it from a proper HTTP address and it works. I'm just being curious on WHY it does not work when opening the HTML file from the harddisk.

Any ideas?

Comment: The requests are blocked by the server. See for example https://tiles.stadiamaps.com/tiles/osm_bright/14/8820/5482.png which also results in a 403 forbidden.

Answer (score 2):

The requests are blocked by the server. See for example https://tiles.stadiamaps.com/tiles/osm_bright/14/8820/5482.png which also results in a 403 forbidden.

According to https://docs.stadiamaps.com/ you will need to supply an API key:

> You will need to include an API key with each request that is made
> outside a web browser. You can generate a key in your account control
> panel. Please take great care not to expose your API key. You do NOT
> need to include it in any files hosted on your website such as
> JavaScript code. API keys should generally only be used for
> server-side or mobile applications.
>
> You can specify your API key via a query string parameter `api_key`, or
> via an `Authorization` header with the value `Stadia-Auth <key>` where
> `<key>` is your API key.

Try to register at Stadia Maps to obtain an API key. Then change your tile server URL accordingly:

```
https://tiles.stadiamaps.com/tiles/osm_bright/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Comment: Helloo scai, I suppose that is not the reason, as it works when I open my test html file using "localhost" on my xampp server, even though I also do not have an API key entered.

Comment: And your server doesn't send an `Authorization` header either? Maybe the server IP is on a whitelist so that no API key is required?

Comment: Nope : it's not OK even with API key : wget answers "connected" then "wait" then "404"

Comment: BTW, before failing, it redirects to `https://stadiamaps.com/styles/osm_bright/...`